# How to setup Cloudera Hadoop to run on Ubuntu localhost?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am trying to run all Hadoop servers on a single Ubuntu localhost. All ports are open and my /etc/hosts file is

```
127.0.0.1   frigate frigate.domain.local    localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

**When trying to install cluster  Cloudera manager fails with the following messages:**

```
Installation failed. Failed to receive heartbeat from agent.

Ensure that the host's hostname is configured properly.
Ensure that port 7182 is accessible on the Cloudera Manager server (check firewall rules).
Ensure that ports 9000 and 9001 are free on the host being added.
Check agent logs in /var/log/cloudera-scm-agent/ on the host being added (some of the logs can be found in the installation details).
```

I run my Ubuntu-12.04 node from home connected by Wifi/dialup modem to my provider. What configuration is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Add your pc ip to /etc/hosts file like

```
# IP pc_name
192.168.3.4 my_pc
```

It will solve the issue.

Comment: Yes this solved to me as well, cloudera manger is on 192.168.1.3 and I can sucesfully install to 192.168.1.4 but adding 192.168.1.3 server0 helped me.

Answer (score 0):

this config is ok for me. hope helpful.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
```

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/cdh-dev/9rczbLkAxlg/lF882T7ZyNoJ

my pc: (ubuntu12.04.2 64bit vm)